# How to power a OLED 128x128 display from 3.3v microcontroller board?

Tags: power, oled

I recently purchased a small 1 inch OLED screen. In the datasheet, it shows the max power requirements as:

**Operation**: 3.5v
**Logic**: 2.6v
**IO**: 3.5v
**Display**: 13.5v

I figure I can directly connect the operation and IO pins to the 3.3v power. I guess for the logic pin, I'd use a voltage divider circuit?
What about the display? Since it's a small little screen, I don't expect the current to be much of an issue, but how do I boost the voltage from 3.3v to 13v?

Since I'm new, I would normally use a pre-made breakout board, but in this case I'd rather learn how to do it instead.

**Edit**: The driver is a **SSD1351**. Here is a link to the datasheet: [SSD1351](https://www.newhavendisplay.com/app_notes/SSD1351.pdf)

**Edit 2**: The datasheet I have for the display is marked as 'Confidential' and doesn't appear available online. I got it sent in email from the manufacturer. So I don't have a link, but I found the current information for the display:

30% of display: 13.3 typical, 17.0 max mA
60% of display: 23.2 typical, 29.0 max mA
100% of display: 33.4 typical, 42.0 max mA

Comment: Do you have any reference, or photo of the module?

Comment: You need to specify the maximum current requirement at 13.5V. Chances are good that the logic and I/O will operate from your 3.3V and you just need a 13.5V source for the display. Please link datasheet for the display.

Comment: if 13.5 is absolute maximum, changes are good that it will opwerate from 12V, still you'll need a way to boost 3.3 up to 12V for that more details would be good.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks, I've linked the datasheet in the description. It's a SSD1351 driver. Not sure where to look for the current requirements. It looks like it is software configurable?

Comment: It's set by a resistor. You need the datasheet for the **display** as well as the driver.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Added the current information. I couldn't find a link for the datasheet and the one sent to me was marked 'Confidential', so I figured it best not to upload it. Even if its common knowledge.

Comment: where do you see 2.6V ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driving OLED displays is easy, but you need to provide two voltages:

- supply for the digital part of the display is 3.3V from your logic
- supply for the display drivers is 10V - 18V from any step-up driver (higher voltage means higher brightness and also higher current)

For inspiration of the supply, here is [breakout with your display display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/684) and also [schematic](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/40756).

Comment: Yes, that's it. It looks like the FAN5331 IC does the work. The datasheet has the same circuit in that schematic. Thanks for that!